# Manjaro / Arch Linux - How do I trust my AspNet Dev Certficate?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, manjaro

I use Manjaro for dotnet development and recently have been having serious problems with SSL.

When I run my web apps I get a warning saying `The ASP.NET Core developer certificate is not trusted. For information about trusting the ASP.NET Core developer certificate, see https://aka.ms/aspnet/https-trust-dev-cert.`

I've been through the link with a fine tooth comb - It's not very helpful to us Linux users and even less helpful to Manjaro / Arch.

This has led me round the houses somewhat trying to wrap my head around exactly what I need to do to actually trust this certificate - what do I run? where is it actually stored?

I've found a lot of information and most of it seems to be quite dated. I've got myself in a bit of a mess now - It's still not working and I've tried many things.

I extrapolated the commands below from an article on Github, but I'm not sure the storage locations are quite right.

```
# Start at home
cd ~

# Create cert
dotnet dev-certs https

# Export cert to current directory
dotnet dev-certs https -ep localhost.crt --format PEM

# Create the paths if necessary
cd /usr/share/ca-certificates
sudo mkdir trust-source
sudo chmod 755 trust-source
cd trust-source
sudo mkdir anchors
sudo chmod 755 anchors
cd ~

# Trust Chromium based browsers
sudo -E dotnet dev-certs https -ep /usr/share/ca-certificates/aspnet/https.crt --format PEM
sudo certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n localhost -i ./localhost.crt
sudo certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n localhost -i ./localhost.crt

# Trust wget
sudo cp localhost.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/aspnetcore-https-localhost.pem
sudo update-ca-trust extract

# Trust dotnet-to-dotnet
sudo cp localhost.crt /etc/ssl/certs/aspnetcore-https-localhost.pem

# Remove cert from current directory
rm localhost.crt
```

I'm almost at the point of giving up and going back to WIndows for work, which I really don't want to have to do as I find Linux far better for front-end development and I find Manjaro far better than Ubuntu generally, which would be my alternative switch over time.

Answer (score 5):

Hope you have not given up yet.

Go here:
https://github.com/BorisWilhelms/create-dotnet-devcert

Steps:

- `git clone git@github.com:BorisWilhelms/create-dotnet-devcert.git`
- `cd create-dotnet-devcert`
- `. ./scripts/arch-create-dotnet-devcert`

And you are done!

Comment: I will give this a try when my other machine is up - at the moment it's partly working and I don't want to break it! I use flatpak for my browsers so I may need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: I guess you need to find out the location of the nssdb directory for each flatpak browser and then extend the NSSDB_PATHS variable in common.sh.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot.